# I'm using jRecorder to save audio, and I want to send comment to php page:

Tags: javascript, jquery, jrecorder

```
        $.jRecorder(     
        { 
            host : 'http://localhost/recorder/acceptfile.php?filename=' +
                    Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1) + ':' +
                    $('#user_id').val() + ':' + 
                    $('#comment').val() ,               

            callback_started_recording:     function(){callback_started();},
            callback_stopped_recording:     function(){callback_stopped(); },
            callback_activityLevel:         function(level){callback_activityLevel(level); },
            callback_activityTime:          function(time){callback_activityTime(time); },

            callback_finished_sending:     function(time){callback_finished_sending();  alert(this.host) },

            swf_path : 'jRecorder.swf',

        }   
    );
```

The problem is "$('#comment').val()" is always empty, because the construct $.jRecorder() take a #comment value before user writing..
How I can't get the text from a textarea!
I tried to do like this: this.host += $("#comment").val();
But it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

To get the content of a textarea try using:

```
$('#textarea').text() ;
```

instead of

```
$('#textarea').val() ;
```